# Passing JSON over Windows-Runtime-Component

Tags: c#, javascript, json, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

To hand over data in Windows Store Apps from Windows Runtime Components to managed code or `JavaScript`, there are besides the primitive types other supported types like `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>`, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and more (see full list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx#PassingToManaged)).

In context of my program the `JSON` should be parsed from a WinRT Component(`C#`,`C++`) and passed to, in my case, `JavaScript` code.

Does anybody have an idea to get the already parsed `JSON` transfered by using the given WinRT types? Or maybe solutions with a minimum of parsing outlay after the handover.

My approach was to use `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, but i couldn't find a smart dynamically solution without creating classes or sth like that.

I'm happy about any input!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found an interesting [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198241.aspx) in the MSDN Magazine about the handling of JSON between Windows Runtime Components, which recommend to serialize the JSON object first to transfer it as a string. Unfortunately i cannot avoid to parse/deserialize it again on the other side.